# How can I get n results of a join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Right now I am using a loop to go trough 100 IDs that I have. Each iteration of the loop does a query to the DB. In my opinion this is not efficient at all. I want to put this into one query. But it's not going my own way to say the least.

Here is the query I have been playing around with. It should give a good idea of what I am trying to do.

```
SELECT
    festival_backers.clown_id,
    festival_backers.user_id
FROM festival_backers
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = festival_backers.user_id
LEFT JOIN festival_backers AS lesser ON lesser.festival_id = 1632 AND lesser.clown_id = festival_backers.clown_id
WHERE festival_backers.festival_id = 1632
  AND lesser.clown_id IN (136541, 1000376982, 222329...)
  AND lesser.user_id NOT IN (136541, 1000376982, 222329...)
GROUP BY festival_backers.clown_id
HAVING COUNT(lesser.clown_id) < 3
ORDER BY (festival_backers.amount + (festival_backers.free_vote / 10)) DESC
LIMIT 300;
```

I am getting nothing with this query.

The result I am looking for.

```
clown_id    | user_id
-----------------------------
136541      | 21324
136541      | 57889
136541      | 89632
1000376982  | 56432
1000376982  | 57343
1000376982  | 23345
222329      | 45456
222329      | 77854
222329      | 67789
```

I am trying to get the users that have backed a clown. But only three of them not more than that. I was able to make query where I got more than three but that's not good (they are just too many).

The reason I use `NOT IN` (following example) is because `user_id` is also used for clowns because they are also users.

```
AND lesser.user_id NOT IN [...]
```

I tried following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269273/736910

Is there a way to maybe use a function or something to limit the amount of results return with a join to three? Or is there some other way to get the result I am looking for?

**UPDATE**

I have different queries... Here is another example that also returns nothing:

```
SELECT
        festival_backers.clown_id,
        festival_backers.user_id
    FROM festival_backers
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = festival_backers.user_id
    INNER JOIN festival_backers AS lesser ON lesser.festival_id = 1632 AND lesser.clown_id = festival_backers.clown_id
    WHERE festival_backers.festival_id = 1632
      AND lesser.clown_id IN (136541, 1000376982, 222329...)
      AND lesser.user_id NOT IN (136541, 1000376982, 222329...)
    GROUP BY festival_backers.clown_id
    HAVING COUNT(festival_backers.clown_id) < 3
    ORDER BY (festival_backers.amount + (festival_backers.free_vote / 10)) DESC
    LIMIT 300;
```

Comment: Why the `LEFT JOIN`???

Comment: I tried a bunch of stuff. This is one example.

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` here is useless because your condition in the `WHERE` clause will turn it into `INNER JOIN`.  Since you don't know why you use `LEFT JOIN`, let's just leave it like that.

Comment: Have you tried removing your 'WHERE' statements individually to see if any results appear? @Eric also appears to be correct about the `LEFT JOIN` as well.

Comment: What's the purpose of the join with `users`? You never use anything from that table.

Comment: Your `HAVING` clause restricts the results to clowns that have fewer than 3 results total, it doesn't just show the first 3 results of each. The question you linked to shows a number of ways to do what you want.

Comment: @Barmar Copy/pasted the query and modified it quickly. It is used in the original.

Comment: You modified it wrong. You have to use `<` in the left join condition with `lesser`.

Comment: I made some corrections to the first query. The second one is with `INNER JOIN` and `HAVING COUNT(festival_backers.clown_id) < 3`.

Comment: You have to use `left join`. That ensures that the results that are higher are not included in the result of the join. Then `count(lesser.columnName)` only counts the non-null rows, and `HAVING` does the correct thing.

Comment: If you're going to modify the query, you need to understand how it works to begin with, otherwise you're just changing things randomly.

Comment: @Barmar just post an answer with the correct modification to the `left join`. This is painful.

Comment: @jnbdz What's the purpose of `GROUP BY` if you don't have any aggregation???

Comment: @Barmar About the `COUNT()` I don't want it to count null rows. I tried it with `count(lesser.columnName)` with `left join`. Even commented out `GROUP BY`. I still get an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269273/1491895) from the question you linked to.

```
SELECT b.clown_id, b.user_id   
FROM festival_backers AS b
LEFT JOIN festival_backers AS lesser 
    ON b.clown_id = lesser.clown_id 
    AND b.user_id < lesser.user_id
    AND lesser.user_id NOT IN (136541, 1000376982, 222329...)
WHERE b.festival_id = 1632
AND b.clown_id IN (136541, 1000376982, 222329...)
AND b.user_id NOT IN (136541, 1000376982, 222329...)
GROUP BY b.clown_id, b.user_id
HAVING COUNT(lesser.user_id) <= 5
```

Note that conditions on the `lesser` table that you're comparing with have to be put in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.

This will return the 5 lowest user IDs for each clown ID. If you want to order them by some other attribute than user ID, change `b.user_id < lesser.user_id` to `b.otherColumn < lesser.otherColumn`.